# How to order nested models using sequelize literals

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to order nested models using  sequelize literals ?

this is my code, but it's not working

```
 const bookmarkedNotices = await RecruitmentNoticeBookmark.findAndCountAll(
          {
            order: [
              [
                { model: RecruitmentNotice, as: 'notice' },
                [
                  Sequelize.literal(
                    "CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN 1 WHEN status = 'finished' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END",
                  ),
                ],
              ],
              [{ model: RecruitmentNotice, as: 'notice' }, 'createdAt', 'DESC'],
            ],
          },
        );
```

Please let me know the solution

Comment: Can you add a generated SQL?